# Creating a list of textfield in Angular 4

Tags: angular, button, textfield

I have an array object which getting the input from textfield.
However, I want to design the textfield in a neat way, it shows only one textfield with a '+' button next to it. Only when it gets filled and the user click on the button, another textfield will be displayed under the previous textfield and so on.

Is there any way to achieve that in Angular 4?

EDIT: Model sample

```
export class Book{
    constructor(
      public id: number,
      public title: string,
      public author: Array<string>){}
}
```

I want it to have json value like this:

```
    {"id": 1,
     "title": "Book A",
     "author": ["personA", "personB", "personC"]
    }
```

Comment: Yes, there are ways. The simplest one being to use a FormArray: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#use-formarray-to-present-an-array-of-formgroups

Comment: I add an anser with simple example, but if you want an example with Reactive Forms, than let me know and I create an example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by simpliest way with `ngModel`-Forms or by little difficult way with `RectiveForms` with `FormArray`.

More about ReactiveForms you can find here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Here is an simple example for solution with `ngModel` an [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wscz9d) is an working example:

**Step 1: Declate an array of Type TextField**

```
editAuthors: any[] = [];
```

**Step 2: Convert your authors array**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bookModel.authors.forEach((author, index) => {
      this.editAuthors.push({ key: 'author'+index, value: author });
    });
  }
```

Fill new editAuthors-Array, which you need for form elemets creation.

**Step 3: Function for you Add-button**

```
addNewTextField(index: number) {
    const newTextField: TextField = {
      key: 'textfield' + index,
      value: ''
    }
    this.textfields.push(newTextField);
  }
```

Here you can set default value fot new textfields.

**Step 4: Submit form**

In this step you should get values from editAuthors-Array and push this to your bookModel.authors-Array.

```
showModel() {
    this.editAuthors.forEach((author, index) => {
      this.bookModel.authors[index] = author.value;
    });
    // do something with new model
  }
```

**Step 5: Template**

```
 <div>
    <label>Book Tiitle</label>
    <input type="text" name="bookTitle" [(ngModel)]="bookModel.title" />
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let author of editAuthors;">
    <label>Author</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="author.value" [name]="author.key" />
  </div>

  <button (click)="addNewAuthor()">Add new Author</button>
  <button type="submit" (click)="showModel()">Submit</button>
```

Iterate through `editAuthors`. Than create `inputs` with `name`-attribute and `[(ngModel)]`. Use `author.value`  for binding data to form elements. With `author.key` add unique `name`-attributes.

**Full TS-file**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  bookModel = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Book 1',
    authors: [
      'Author 1',
      'Author 2',
      'Author 3'
    ]
  };

  editAuthors: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bookModel.authors.forEach((author, index) => {
      this.editAuthors.push({ key: 'author'+index, value: author });
    });
  }

  addNewAuthor() {
    this.editAuthors.push({ key: 'author'+this.editAuthors.length+1, value: '' });
  }

  showModel() {
    this.editAuthors.forEach((author, index) => {
      this.bookModel.authors[index] = author.value;
    });
    console.log(this.bookModel);
  }

}
```

Comment: I have the model with several attributes and one of them is array. I want to only set the textfield for this particular attribute. How to do so?

Comment: @OreoFanatics can you post example of your model?

Comment: @OreoFanatics i have updated my answer and the working example